# How to have two <p> elements within a table td cell not effect the size of the cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a calendar in which I have used JS to retrieve this year's calendar. When I want to add a `<p>` element to a specific date within the calendar, the 7-day cells no longer keep the same width. I have been successful in placing the two strings within the cell at different locations, however, I am unable to control the cells width without losing the desired location within the cell.

The CSS style

```
td {
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
     height: 200px;
     vertical-align: top;
     padding:5px;
 }
 td > p {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
```

I am just using the JS produced date and `<p>Dinner Party</p>` as my tester data for the cell.

Comment: The DOM inspector tool should show you exactly how the layout has been determined.

Comment: Along with what Pointy wrote, your browser likely has a default margin and/or padding pixels added to `p`. Reset it by setting margin and padding values to 0.

Comment: You may consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question that shows your issue using the snippit tool.